# Calculating fields with filters in Django

Tags: python, django

I am extremely new to Django and kinda new to python and programming in general, so i may be asking a dumb question. I am trying to track medications in our inventory at work. Here is my model for the inventory in our safe

```
class Safe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    drug_name = models.ForeignKey('components.Drug', related_name='drug_remove', on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=0)
    amount_removed = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount_added = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    incident_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=0, blank=True)
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=0, blank=True)
    medic_unit = models.ForeignKey('components.MedicUnit', related_name='medic_unit', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
    free_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=0, blank =True)
    drug_total = computed_property.ComputedIntegerField(compute_from='add_drug')
```

I would like to store the medication total for each drug in the database. I understand from researching this that storing totals isn't best practice in most cases but I believe this is one exception. Obviously the calculated integer field isn't the answer, but none of my research has gotten me any closer to the answer. My guess is that I first need to filter by 'drug_name' and then calculate the added or subtracted drugs from the previous total in a function within my model. Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Comment: I might be getting wrongly what you need. But it seems to me that you just need to compute the `drug_total + drug_added - drug_removed` is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I might be getting wrongly what you need. But it seems to me that you just need to compute the `drug_total + drug_added - drug_removed` is that correct?
Add this to the bottom of your model:

```
def get_current_amount_of_drug(self):
    return self.drug_total - self.drug_removed + self.drug_added
```

Then from any view or other place where you need it - you can just call

```
safe = Safe.objects.filter(drug_name="My Drug").first() # or however you filter them and then just get
safe.get_current_amount_of_drug()
```

Maybe the documentation would help you more:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem I'm having now is that i get a "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Morphine 10mg/1ml'" with the Safe.objects.filter() function. I did some research and tried to call the model first then the field name but that gives me another error.

Comment: The drug_name seems to be a foreign key to another table. It expects there id or Drug object. So just pass in the filter a Drug object

Comment: Yup, passing in the filter to make the drug_name a Drug object worked. Thanks!!!